# Magento 2: get Stock quantity from custom source

Tags: magento2, magento-2.3

I use this code to retrieve stock quantity by product id.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$StockState = $objectManager->get('\Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockStateInterface');
$qty = $StockState->getStockQty($product->getId(), $product->getStore()->getWebsiteId());
```

This snippet returns only "default source" quantity.
My goal consist to retrieve "mycustom source" quantity such as:

[image]

Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure. See below codes:

```
<?php
namespace YourNameSpace;

use Magento\InventoryApi\Api\SourceItemRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder;


class YourClass
{
    /**
     * @var SourceItemRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected SourceItemRepositoryInterface $sourceItems;

    /**
     * @var SearchCriteriaBuilder
     */
    protected SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder;


    /**
     * @param SourceItemRepositoryInterface $sourceItems
     * @param SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder
     */
    public function __construct(
        
        SourceItemRepositoryInterface $sourceItems,
        SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder
    ){
        $this->sourceItems = $sourceItems;
        $this->searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
    }


    public function yourFunction() {
            //Set source
            $sku = $product->getSku();
            $searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder
                ->addFilter('sku', $sku)
                ->create();
            $sourceItemData = $this->sourceItems->getList($searchCriteria);
            foreach ($sourceItemData->getItems() as $sourceItem){
                //Get source qty
                $sourceItem->getQuantity()
                //Get source code
                $sourceItem->getSourceCode();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You just need to provide SKU, and then you will get 8 from MyCustom Source and 47 from Default Source. I simplified the codes to be a more readable form, please modify it when you use them.

Comment: Hello sir, this code doesn't work for my scope because I use a custom php file outside Magento.  As you see, I call the object manager in this mode "$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();"

Comment: You can modify my code to fit your needs. The direction is the same. Just change dependency injection to `$objectmanager`.